# Regularity of $\exp(f)$ for $f\in BMO$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

We say that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T}^d)$ is in $BMO(\mathbb{T}^d)$, if
$$ \|f\|_{BMO} = \sup_{Q\subset\mathbb{T}^d}\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q |f(x)-(f)_Q|\mathrm{d}x < \infty,$$
where $(f)_Q$ is the mean integral over $Q$ and $\sup$ is taken over all cubes $Q\subset\mathbb{T}^d$.

I want to ask what I can say about the regularity of $\exp(f)$ for $f\in BMO$. So far I know that from the John-Nirenberg inequality, for any cube $Q$ we have
$$ \int_Q \exp\left(\frac{|f-(f)_Q|}{\|f\|_{BMO}}\right)\mathrm{d}x < \infty. $$
So if $\|f\|_{BMO}$ is small enough, $\exp(f)\in L^p(\mathbb{T}^d)$ for $p<\frac{1}{\|f\|_{BMO}}$.

However, I was wondering if I can say something more, probably under some additional conditions on $f$. In particular, what are the necessary conditions on $f$ to have also $\exp(f)\in BMO$?

For example, the function $f(x)=\log|x|$ satisfies this condition, as $e^{\log|x|}=|x|$ is bounded on torus and so is in $BMO$.

I would be very grateful for any help and references about such results.